# Why am I unable to migrate when other files use my models in Heroku?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, deployment

For context, I have an application that works perfectly fine locally, after some fiddling with the database. It uses a react frontend, with a django backend for internal api calls. However, on a new, fresh download, with a new, fresh database, I always get an error saying `relation "claims" does not exist`, where Claims is the name of a table in my database, in the form of a model.

I have been able to bypass this error by commenting out all code that uses the model, then slowly migrating every single table, one at a time, then uncommenting out the code that uses the model.

This is incredibly tedious, but it works in a local environment. However, as I attempt to push this into production, I am using Heroku, and I am unable to make multiple commits in the same way, as it seems the database gets reset everytime there is a new update.

Am I missing something? I feel as though there must be something I am doing incorrectly here, but I have not been able to find anything other than posts saying to reset all my migrations, and redoing the makemigrations command. This method hasn't worked for me in Heroku, because I need to do each migration individually, as I said before.

For reference, here are my related files:
models.py

```py
class Claims(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    refId = models.CharField(db_column='refId', unique=True, max_length=10)  # Field name made lowercase.
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    distributor = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, choices=claimStatus.choices, default=claimStatus.active)  # This field type is a guess.

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'claims'
        unique_together = (('id', 'refId'),)
```

migrations/0001_initial.py

```py
from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Claims',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('refId', models.CharField(db_column='refId', max_length=10, unique=True)),
                ('title', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20, null=True)),
                ('description', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=256, null=True)),
                ('image', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=70, null=True)),
                ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('start', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('end', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('distributor', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20, null=True)),
                ('status', models.TextField(blank=True, choices=[('ACTIVE', 'Active'), ('INACTIVE', 'Inactive'), ('DISCONTINUED', 'Discontinued')], default='ACTIVE', null=True)),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'claims',
                'managed': True,
                'unique_together': {('id', 'refId')},
            },
        ),
    ]
```

useClaim.py

```py
from .models import *
claim, created = Claims.objects.get_or_create(
    refId = "DROPTEST",
    title = "DROPTEST",
    description ="DROPTEST",
    image = "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmcPjQ7iaZ8exuZnH1awHZtkQPyL3TRT1S46wVJxwucay5",
    created_at = None,
    start = None,
    end = None,
    distributor = "DROPTEST",
    status = claimStatus.active
)
claim.save()
```

Comment: are you using Sqlite as the database in Heroku?

Comment: I am using postgres

Comment: uses some tool to access directly database and check if you have `claims` in database.

Comment: Why do you run code that makes a query on the module level / scope? You shouldn't be making any queries outside some method / function, unless that file is not imported at the start. If you want to do such setup write a data migration or do it in the `ready` method of the app config.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat That was the issue! thank you so much!

Comment: @yeeshue99 don't put the answer in the question itself. You can answer the question yourself, this is called a self answer and it is in fact encouraged to do it.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I didn't see the button to answer my own question after posting. Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AbdulAzizBarkat, I found that the issue was not in the compilation level of the application as I had originally thought. I had code modifying/referencing the models before they were migrated. I tried the `ready` method of AppConfig, however that did not work for me. Instead, I took the database initialization and wrote a migration operation instead, and that worked wonderfully.